# tmux - Catch 22 with "unknown key: WheelUpPane" for osx and Ubuntu

Tags: tmux

Recently tmux changed a lot of mouse stuff for the better.

I've got a bit stuck however because I need to have

```
bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "send-keys -M" "if -Ft= '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t=; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"
bind -n WheelDownPane select-pane -t= \; send-keys -M
```

in order to be able to scroll up and down in OSX

However having those lines in my .tmux.conf (that I like to share between OS's) in Ubuntu leads to

```
/home/durrantm/.tmux.conf:75: unknown key: WheelUpPane                                                   [0/0]
/home/durrantm/.tmux.conf:76: unknown key: WheelDownPane
```

and if I remove them then I can't scroll in OSX when I apply changes with

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Comment: Versions of tmux in Ubuntu and OSX?

Comment: 2.1 in osx and 1.9a in Ubuntu.  I've `sudo apt-get install`d tmux 2.1 but can't figure out how to activate it

Comment: Might be a good idea to create a [OS-dependant tmux config section](http://superuser.com/a/539657/287951) so you can issue these commands just for MacOSX.

Comment: What do you mean by "activating it"? If you `apt-get install`ed tmux 2.1, that should be the binary in `/usr/bin/tmux`. Test with `tmux -V`. Keep in mind you will need to quit all your sessions and restart them.